# /dev/ttyAMA0 only working when another USB/RS232 converter plugged in

Tags: serial

A strange one!

I'm trying to use the on-board UART, /dev/ttyAMA0, with [dixprs](https://sites.google.com/site/dixprs/).

I'm on Raspbian Jessie, and have:

- Taken the ttyAMA console out of /boot/cmdline.txt
- Disabled agetty on ttyAMA0 with "/bin/systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service" (and confirmed it's no longer running after a reboot)
- Checked the pi user is a member of tty and dialout groups

Now, if I plug in a random Prolific USB->RS232 adaptor (which appears as /dev/ttyUSB0), /dev/ttyAMA0 suddenly starts working!

If I remove it and restart the app, it stops - until I re-insert the Prolific device and restart the app again [EDIT 2016-02-02: doesn't even need an app restart to take effect. As soon as ttyUSB0 removed, it stops working; as soon as it's reinserted, it starts again. dixprs keeps the char device open throughout, I think]. (I've grepped the python in question for any hard-coded mentions of ttyUSB0, just in case, and lsof shows only ttyAMA0 in use while the app is running.)

It sort of *feels* like the presence of the USB device causes some permissions to be dynamically set, but I can't think nor see what...

Anything obvious I'm missing?

Edit to add:

`pi@mb7ups-pi:~ $ uname -a
Linux mb7ups-pi 4.1.13+ #826 PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:13:22 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
pi@mb7ups-pi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@mb7ups-pi:~ $ ls -l /dev/ttyAMA0 /dev/ttyUSB* # Without USB device plugged in
ls: cannot access /dev/ttyUSB*: No such file or directory
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 204, 64 Feb  3 09:08 /dev/ttyAMA0
pi@mb7ups-pi:~ $ ls -l /dev/ttyAMA0 /dev/ttyUSB* # With USB device plugged in
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 204, 64 Feb  3 09:08 /dev/ttyAMA0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  0 Feb  3 09:10 /dev/ttyUSB0
pi@mb7ups-pi:~ $ groups
pi adm tty dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi`

Edit a bit more: OK, it's not permissions. If I run Python as root (yes, I know... testing :-p), it still shows the same behaviour. I'm wondering if there's some hardware issue that the addition of the Prolific is triggering...

Comment: try to read-write to that tty with and without your USB device - is it working ok? Like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138342/how-to-read-write-to-tty-device) UPD 3/2/2016 : OK, and now take a look - is your USB-attached RS-232 converter receives *always* the same `/dev/xxx` entry? Regardless of replugs and reboots?

Comment: Could you add details of your kernel and operating system plus permissions to your post?  E.g. uname -a, cat /etc/os-release, ls -l /dev/ttyAMA0.  Permissions before and after plugging in the USB device please.

Comment: @joan Sorry - added!

Comment: I can `cat /dev/ttyAMA0` in all circumstances - it returns immediately with no error both with and without the USB device plugged in. The modem (a Pi-TNC) doesn't speak an ASCII protocol so not easy to send it meaningful data from minicom or similar, but no permission denied errors in evidence at least...

Comment: Those permissions look correct (`crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 204, 64 Feb  3 09:08 /dev/ttyAMA0`) before and after.  Have you used lsof to see if anything else has the device open?  E.g. sudo apt-get install lsof; sudo lsof /dev/ttyAMA0.

Comment: Yep, lsof shows the device being open OK with and without USB plugged in:
`dixprs.py 494   pi    9u   CHR 204,64      0t0   12 /dev/ttyAMA0`

(Edit: dixprs.py is the expected process - nothing else has it open.)

Answer (score 2):

So... after swapping to a different PSU, all seems to be as it should with the world.

Sorry for the slightly wild goose chase folks!